# Android app measuring network latency from device to device

Tags: android, tcp, network-programming, udp, timestamp

I need to write an android app that measures network latency from android device to android device (app to app). I am not interested in ping (ICMP) as the apps will be testing a very congested network. The protocols I am interested in are TCP and UDP. I have searched the app stores and cannot find what I am looking for. Does anyone have an resources on, have any ideas, or know how to send a TCP or UDP packet with a timestamp from an android app?

I am at a real loss here and not sure if I am even thinking about the problem correctly. I welcome any advice or discussion that leads towards a solution. And if solved, I will gladly post the solution code here for others see and use. Thanks!

Comment: Can you measure it in a round trip?  Send a message from A to B and then back to A.

Comment: Yes, round trip is fine; I'll just divide it in half.